# Model Validation from Migration - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, validation, model

*Beginner in Ruby on Rails*

I have tables in PostgreSql Database. I was able to dump the schema from the existing database to the Ruby schema and migrate it (Which made save like a lot of time for me)

Now I am wondering if there is a way to implement Model Validation from Migration Validation. I have data validations implemented on the fields of table. I want to implement same validations to the Model as well. Is there a way to do it with minimal codes or do I have to manually create validations in each model?

For eg:

```
create_table "corporates", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "corporate_no", limit: 13, null: false
   t.string "corporate_name", null: false
   t.boolean "active", default: true
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.index ["corporate_no"], name: "corporates_corporate_no_key", unique: true
end
```

Now I want to implement this validation in my model as

```
class Corporate < ApplicationRecord
   validates :corporate_no, presence: true, limit: 13
   validates :corporate_name, presence: true
   validates :active, default: true
end
```

P.S. Those Model Validations may be wrong. Did I say I was beginner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that there's something out of the box in Rails.

But I've found a gem [schema_validations](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_validations) which probably does, what you're looking for.

The only difference is that this gem follows DRY approach and doesn't generate validations in the model. For example, you have `users` table:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email, null: false, limit: 30
  t.boolean :confirmed, null: false
end
```

This gem won't generate validations as you expect:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :confirmed, presence: true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
end
```

You're still going to have clean `User` model, but the fields are validated:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And it can be configured if you don't need validations on every model.

Comment: I just went through the documentation of schema_validations. Its a neat gem. I like it. However, I saw that there are limitations on what kind of validations it can perform. Like having default value or precision. But hey! Something is better than nothing. Right?